# watir webdriver - uploading file when browser is running on a remote/different OS

Tags: windows, unix, selenium, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir webdriver on an Ubuntu box to drive IE (but the same problem exists on other browsers) on a Windows VM.
When I try to upload a file with

---

```
browser.file_field(:name => 'file_upload').set(path)
```

---

the call fails in both cases I can think of:

1. if I set 'path' to something like "C:\document.doc", the call stops with a 'file not found' before handing it over to the remote browser, because it checks the local (ubuntu) filesystem where that is not a valid path
2. if I hand it something like '/home/users/username/document.doc' for the value of path, the call itself is happy, hands it over to the remote IE which is then unhappy because, logically, that is not a valid path on a Windows box.

Does anyone have an idea how to get around this conundrum?

Thanks a lot!